# Div only appends once

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, append

I had the following code:

```
    switch (caseType) {
        case "dates":
            $.each(array.reverse(), function (index, arr) {
                var $accordionOption = $('<div />', {
                    "class": "option",
                    "data-select": 'option',
                    "data-action": 'makePie',
                    text: arr
                });

                $accordionOption.appendTo($accordionOptionContainer);
                $accordionOption.click(function () {
                    cache.select(this);
                });
            });
            break;
        case "cohort":
            $.each(array, function (index, arr) {
                var $accordionOption = $('<div />', {
                    "class": "option",
                    "data-select": 'option',
                    "data-action": 'makePie',
                    text: arr
                });

                $accordionOption.appendTo($accordionOptionContainer);
                $accordionOption.click(function () {
                    cache.select(this);
                });
            });
            break;
        case "period":

            $.each(array, function (index, arr) {
                console.log(arr)
                var $accordionOption = $('<div />', {
                    "class": "option",
                    "data-select": 'option',
                    "data-action": 'makePie',
                    text: arr
                });

                $accordionOption.appendTo($accordionOptionContainer);
                $accordionOption.click(function () {
                    cache.select(this);
                });
            });
            break;

    }
```

And it worked, it makes the element and appends it to the DOM.

I wanted to clean it up so I tried this:

```
    var $accordionOption = $('<div />', {
        "class": "option",
        "data-select": 'option',
        "data-action": 'makePie'
    });

    switch (caseType) {
        case "dates":
            $.each(array.reverse(), function (index, arr) {
                $accordionOption.text(arr);
                $accordionOption.appendTo($accordionOptionContainer);
            });
            break;
        case "cohort":
            $.each(array, function (index, arr) {
                $accordionOption.text(arr);
                $accordionOption.appendTo($accordionOptionContainer);
            });
            break;
        case "period":

            $.each(array, function (index, arr) {
                $accordionOption.text(arr);
                $accordionOption.appendTo($accordionOptionContainer);
            });
            break;
    }
    $accordionOption.click(function () {
        cache.select(this);
    });
```

However, I noticed that it only appends the last array item in the loop. Is this because the variable has to be recreated each time? Or because it is adding everything to accordion option before it appends? Or overwriting the same variable?

My final solution:

---

```
    function getDiv() {
        return $('<div />', {
            "class": "option",
            "data-select": 'option',
            "data-action": 'makeTable'
        });
    }

    $.each(caseType == "dates" ? array.reverse() : array, function (index, arr) {
        var $accordionOption = getDiv()
                .text(arr)
                .click(function () { cache.select(this) })
                .appendTo($accordionOptionContainer);
    });
```

Comment: its because you only create 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about a simple inline if as the only difference is the array in `dates`.

```js
$.each(caseType == "dates" ? array.reverse() : array, function(index, arr) {
  var $accordionOption = $('<div />', {
    "class": "option",
    "data-select": 'option',
    "data-action": 'makePie'
  });
  $accordionOption.text(arr);
  $accordionOption.appendTo($accordionOptionContainer);
  $accordionOption.click(function() {
    cache.select(this);
  });
});
```

Comment: Oh, you're good. I will try that. I thought about the case "default" for the other two but this is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You are appending the same element each time.

```
$('<div />')
```

creates an element and this is the same one apended each time

change to something like this:

```
 function getDiv(){
     return  $('<div />', {
        "class": "option",
        "data-select": 'option',
        "data-action": 'makePie'
    });}

    switch (caseType) {
        case "dates":
            $.each(array.reverse(), function (index, arr) {
                $accordionOption.text(arr);
                $accordionOption.appendTo(getDiv());
            });
            break;
        case "cohort":
            $.each(array, function (index, arr) {
                $accordionOption.text(arr);
                $accordionOption.appendTo(getDiv());
            });
            break;
        case "period":

            $.each(array, function (index, arr) {
                $accordionOption.text(arr);
                $accordionOption.appendTo(getDiv());
            });
            break;
    }
    $accordionOption.click(function () {
        cache.select(this);
    });
```